# Raspberry Pi can't print to wireless printer

Tags: printing, raspbian

I can print to my wireless printer from my laptop just fine, but I'm having trouble getting it to work from my Raspberry Pi.  I found some instructions that said to install cups-client, then edit the cups client.conf file.  However, after installing cups-client I didn't have the etc/cups directory.  I tried also installing cups and found that the directory was created after that, but I still did not have the .conf file.  I found an example file in /usr/share/doc/libcups2/examples and copied it to the cups directory. I then added `ServerName [IP of my printer]:631` and tried printing again, but it still didn't work.  I tried using lpr but nothing prints, and in LibreOffice the only printer listed is Generic Printer.  lpstat doesn't output anything, and when I run `lpstat -t` I get

`scheduler is running
no system default destination
lpstat: -1 not supported!
lpstat: -1 not supported!
lpstat: -1 not supported!
lpstat: -1 not supported!`

Similarly, most other lpstat options give the not supported error.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with wireless printing via CUPS, but in the past I've had to setup a driver to get CUPS working over USB.

This page might help: https://www.openprinting.org/drivers. I'd also test connecting it via USB first.

Apologies if I couldn't be of more help. Hoping someone with a bit more experience comes along...